# Better way to find last used row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the last row the same way I found the last column:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1,Sheets("Sheet2").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

I know this way but it is not as helpful as the prior would be:

```
u = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
```

I tried:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("Sheet2",1).Rowa.Count).End(xlToUP).Column
```

Synopsis: I would like the below way for last row.

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1,Sheets("Sheet2").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Comment: Why not using `Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count`?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba

Comment: but in essence `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1,Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: I am using a for loop that changes so I want the cell format. Changing a range is difficult for me where having a cell is a lot easier.

Comment: It return this, "Run-time error '1004'.

Comment: [I found this very valuable and hope you will to](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/find-last-row-column-cell/)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You should use a with statement to qualify both your `Rows` and `Columns` counts.  This will prevent any errors while working with older pre 2007 and newer 2007 Excel Workbooks.

Last Column

```
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
```

Last Row

```
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Or

```
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Comment: For both of the ways to find the last row don't work. I keep getting "Run-Time Error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method" with both of them.

Comment: this code returns "1" on a blank sheet, how is this possible? I want it to return if there is no value inside.

Comment: @smartini because this méthode return a row (empty or not) and return by the end the row if it contains value. 2 possibilities : check if A1 = vbnullstring or use find method

Comment: All three are wrong. The first one will return wrong value if the last column is filled, the other two will return wrong value if the last row is filled.

Comment: It also doesn't catch hidden rows/columns

Answer (score 12):

How is this?

```
dim rownum as integer
dim colnum as integer
dim lstrow as integer
dim lstcol as integer
dim r as range

'finds the last row

lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'finds the last column

lastcol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

'sets the range

set r = range(cells(rownum,colnum), cells(lstrow,lstcol))
```

Comment: I'd use a Long for the rows

Answer (score 6):

This function should do the trick if you want to specify a particular sheet. I took the solution from user6432984 and modified it to not throw any errors. I am using Excel 2016 so it may not work for older versions:

```
Function findLastRow(ByVal inputSheet As Worksheet) As Integer
    findLastRow = inputSheet.cellS(inputSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

This is the code to run if you are already working in the sheet you want to find the last row of:

```
Dim lastRow as Integer
lastRow = cellS(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: It has the same problems as user6432984 answer (mentioned in the comments) e.g. with hidden rows

Answer (score 2):

I use this routine to find the count of data rows.  There is a minimum of overhead required, but by counting using a decreasing scale, even a very large result requires few iterations.  For example, a result of 28,395 would only require 2 + 8 + 3 + 9 + 5, or 27 times through the loop, instead of a time-expensive 28,395 times.

Even were we to multiply that by 10 (283,950), the iteration count is the same 27 times.

```
Dim lWorksheetRecordCountScaler as Long
Dim lWorksheetRecordCount as Long

Const sDataColumn = "A"   '<----Set to column that has data in all rows (Code, ID, etc.)

    'Count the data records
    lWorksheetRecordCountScaler = 100000  'Begin by counting in 100,000-record bites
    lWorksheetRecordCount = lWorksheetRecordCountScaler

    While lWorksheetRecordCountScaler >= 1

        While Sheets("Sheet2").Range(sDataColumn & lWorksheetRecordCount + 2).Formula > " "
            lWorksheetRecordCount = lWorksheetRecordCount + lWorksheetRecordCountScaler
        Wend

        'To the beginning of the previous bite, count 1/10th of the scale from there
        lWorksheetRecordCount = lWorksheetRecordCount - lWorksheetRecordCountScaler
        lWorksheetRecordCountScaler = lWorksheetRecordCountScaler / 10

    Wend

    lWorksheetRecordCount = lWorksheetRecordCount + 1   'Final answer
```

Answer (score 2):

This gives you the last used row in a specified column.

Optionally you can specify the worksheet, otherwise it will take the active sheet.

```vb
Function getLastRow(col As Integer, Optional ws As Worksheet) As Long

    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    If ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).Value <> "" Then
        getLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).Row
        Exit Function
    End If

    getLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row

    If shtRowCount = 1 Then
        If ws.Cells(1, col) = "" Then
            getLastRow = 0
        Else
            getLastRow = 1
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim lgLastRow As Long
    lgLastRow = getLastRow(2) 'Column B

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way I've seen to find the last cell.

```
MsgBox ActiveSheet.UsedRage.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
```

One of the disadvantages to using this is that it's not always accurate. If you use it then delete the last few rows and use it again, it does not always update. Saving your workbook before using this seems to force it to update though.

Using the next bit of code after updating the table (or refreshing the query that feeds the table) forces everything to update before finding the last row. But, it's been reported that it makes excel crash. Either way, calling this before trying to find the last row will ensure the table has finished updating first.

```
Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
```

Another way to get the last row for any given column, if you don't mind the overhead.

```
Function GetLastRow(col, row)
    ' col and row are where we will start.
    ' We will find the last row for the given column.
    Do Until ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col) = ""
        row = row + 1
    Loop
    GetLastRow = row
End Function
```

Comment: I'd have to disagree with you there for the reasons you've given.  I've found either the `xlUp/xlLeft` method for specific columns/rows or `Find("*")` for last cell on sheet to be the most reliable methods.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I couldn't get the code in the accepted answer to work for me. But the code I posted works well for me.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Find method work but you need test if result is nothing in case of all row are vbnullstring and .End(xlUp).Row return last row not empty or the first cell of column

Comment: @MatthewGoheen this answer is the simplest. It works so long as there is no blank cell in the middle of the column. last line should read GetLastRow = row - 1 ?

Comment: the code "ActiveSheet.UsedRage.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row" causes a run-time error when executed on a new (blank or empty) worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

**Problems with normal methods**

Account for Blank Rows / Columns -
If you have blank rows or columns at the beginning of your data then methods like UsedRange.Rows.Count and UsedRange.Columns.Count will skip over these blank rows (although they do account for any blank rows / columns that might break up the data), so if you refer to ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count you will skip lines in cases where there are blank rows at the top of your sheet, for example on this sheet:

[image: Example Sheet with Blank Top Row]

This will skip the top row from the count and return 11:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

This code will include the blank row and return 12 instead:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Cells(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).Row
```

The same issue applies to columns.

Full Sheets -
Identifying the last row or column can be difficult if your sheet is full (this only matters if either your data contains over a million lines or might have values in the final rows or columns of your data). For example, if you use xlEndUp or similar and the cell you're referring to is populated then the code will skip over data, in extreme cases your entire data set can be skipped if for example the data continues from the last row of the sheet (where you start your xlEndUp) solidly up to the first row (in this case the result would be 1).

```
'This code works, but... 
'Will not function as intended if there is data in the cell you start with (Cell A:1048576).
Dim Sht1 as Range: Set Sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Sht1.Cells(Sht1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Columns with blank rows -
The above code also assumes that your data extends the entire way down column 1, if you have blank entries in column 1 you may lose rows as the code will find the first filled row from the bottom *only* for column 1.

Unnecessary Looping -
Self explanatory,  best to avoid looping where possible as if you're dealing with a lot of data and repeating the looping process often it can slow down your code.

**Solution**

Note that this is targeted at finding the last "Used" Row or Column on an entire sheet, this doesn't work if you just want the last cell in a specific range.

I've setup some Functions here

```
Private Function GetLastRow(Sheet As Worksheet)
'Gets last used row # on sheet.
GetLastRow = Sheet.UsedRange.Cells(Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 1).Row
End Function

Private Function GetLastCol(Sheet As Worksheet)
'Gets last used column # on sheet.
GetLastCol = Sheet.UsedRange.Cells(1, Sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
End Function
```

Examples of calling these Functions:

```
Sub CallFunctions()
    'Define the Target Worksheet  we're interested in:
    Dim Sht1 As Worksheet: Set Sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    'Print the last row and column numbers:
    Debug.Print "Last Row = "; GetLastRow(Sht1)
    Debug.Print "Last Col = "; GetLastCol(Sht1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I preferred search last blank cell:

Il you want last empty cell of column you can do that

```
Dim sh as Worksheet, r as range
set sh = ActiveWorksheet 'if you want an other it's possible

'find a value 
'Columns("A:D") 'to check on multiple columns 
Set r = sh.Columns("A").Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
'no value return first row
If r Is Nothing Then Set r = sh.Cells(1, "A") Else Set r = sh1.Cells(r.Row + 1, "A")
```

If this is to insert new row, find on multiple columns is a good choice because first column can contains less rows than next columns

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function extensively.  As pointed out above, using other methods can sometimes give inaccurate results due to used range updates, gaps in the data, or different columns having different row counts.

Example of use:

```
lastRow=FindRange("Sheet1","A1:A1000")
```

would return the last occupied row number of the **entire** range.  You can specify any range you want from single columns to random rows, eg FindRange("Sheet1","A100:A150")

```
Public Function FindRange(inSheet As String, inRange As String) As Long
    Set fr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(inSheet).Range(inRange).find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not fr Is Nothing Then FindRange = fr.row Else FindRange = 0
End Function
```