# Excel 2016- How to detect the last cell on a column in another worksheet?

Tags: worksheet, excel-2016

I have two worksheets, `Sheet1` and `Data`.
The total number of rows in `Data` is always changing depending on a database.

Now in `Sheet1` I wanted to calculate the `SUM` of a column in `Data`

I understand that `=SUM('Data'!R2:R100)` will give the `SUM` of cells from `R2` to `R100`, but in `Data` does not always contain 100 rows, it can be more or less.

So how can I enhance the formula so that it can always `SUM` until the last row of `Data`?
Thanks for any advice in advance!

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you getting through: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/excel-vba-better-way-to-find-last-row

Comment: Thanks you, but is it possible to do it using a cell formula?

Comment: Just go for maximum row, maybe 100000?. I mean set the row number to the maximum value it can go. `SUM` function will skip the blank cells and give sum of values from non-blank cells.

Comment: I thought of this too @RehbanKhatri, but the data will be increasing from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is all together, you can use `COUNTA()` to count the number of non-empty cells in any column. You can then infer (again, assuming you have no random blank rows) the total number of rows.

```
=COUNTA(Data!R:R)
```

But from what I understand, you just want to sum the entire column. Therefore, you don't even need to worry about the rows, just use:

```
=SUM(Data!R:R)
```

This will sum up the entire column `R`.