# How to quickly count the number of lines in multiple text files?

Tags: vba, excel, row, counter

I have a more than 100 text files and I have to count the lines for each of them. `Column A` lists the file name, located in the folder specified in `E1`. Several files have more than 1 million lines, causing the script to run a terrifyingly long time.

[image: screenshot]

```
Sub counter()
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim ts As TextStream
    Dim longtext As String
    Dim lines As Variant
    Dim GoToNum As Integer
    Dim Start As Integer
    GoToNum = 2
    Start = 3

    Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(Start, 1))
        GoToNum = GoToNum + 1
        Start = Start + 1
    Loop

    For i = 3 To GoToNum
        If Cells(i, 2).Value <= Cells(2, 5).Value Then
            ConOrg = Cells(1, 4).Value & "\" & Cells(i, 1).Value

            Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(ConOrg, ForReading, False)
            longtext = ts.ReadAll

            ts.Close
            lines = Split(longtext, vbLf)
            Cells(i, 3) = UBound(lines) - LBound(lines) - 1

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

How can I get the number of the last row (**from the text file**) to avoid the counting line by line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EXCEL-VBA better way to find last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/excel-vba-better-way-to-find-last-row)

Comment: @Black Cornail: No, this question is about getting the line count in a text file.

Comment: You already have it:  `UBound(lines)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### *How to count the lines in a text file using VBA:*

The fastest method depends on the size of the file(s) you're processing:

|  | # of lines | filesize | [`Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/open-statement) statement | [`FileSystemObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **one GIANT file** | 1.7 million | 40mb × 1 | ❌ 25.2 sec | ✔️ **2.1 sec** |
| **many sᴍᴀʟʟ files** | 6 | 14b × 10,000 | ✔️ **1.3 sec** | ❌ 18.9 sec |
|  |  |  | ***better for** sᴍᴀʟʟ **files*** | ***better for* BIG *files*** |

---

### → Better for <sup><sub>small</sub></sup> Files:

```
Function countLF(fName As String) As Long
  Dim st As String
  Open fName For Input As #1: st = Input(LOF(1), 1): Close #1
  countLF = Len(st) - Len(Replace(st, vbLf, "")) + 1
End Function
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Debug.Print countLF("c:\test.txt")
```

---

### → Better for LARGE Files:

```
Function countLines(fName As String) As Long
  countLines=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fName, 8, True).Line
End Function
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Debug.Print countLines("c:\test.txt")
```

---

<sub>***More Benchmarking** of other tested variations:*  (2500 tiny text files)</sub>
<sub>**Binary Access/Get**               (4.32s) Kill=1.17s . . .  Open F `For Binary Access Read As #1:ReDim...Get #1,,bytes</sub>
<sub>**Line Input/LineInput**            (4.44s) Kill=1.11s . . .  Open F For Input As #iFile...Line Input #1,st</sub>
<sub>**Early Bind/ReuseObj**  (5.25s) Del=1.12s . . .  Set o=New Scripting.FileSystemObject':st=o.OpenTextFile(F).ReadAll()</sub>
<sub>**Early Bind/FreshObj** (11.98s) Del=1.35s . . .  Set o=New Scripting.FileSystemObject':st=o.OpenTextFile(F).ReadAll()</sub>
<sub>**LateBind/ReuseObj**    (6.25s) Del=1.47s . . .  Set o=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")</sub>
<sub>**LateBind/FreshObj**   (13.59s) Del=2.29s . . .  With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")</sub>

Comment: In the table above, shouldnt the Better for Big and Better for Small labels be switched?

Comment: @psycoperl it seems so when looking at the ✔ and the text after, so I've made the edit.

Answer (score 3):

Give this function a try. It uses the `FileSystemObject`. Should be faster than read the whole file and split it into single lines. Inspired from [Hey, Scripting guy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2004/10/12/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-lines-in-a-text-file/)

```
Function countLines(fName As String) As Long

    Const ForReading = 1
    Dim objFSO  As Object, objTextFile As Object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fName, ForReading)
    objTextFile.ReadAll
    countLines = objTextFile.Line
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach would be to use Power Query (Get & Transform Data):

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("C:\Users\me\MyFolder"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Extension] = ".txt"),
    #"Added Row Count" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Rows In File", each Table.RowCount(Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary([Content])})), Int64.Type),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Row Count",{"Name", "Rows In File"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

This works pretty fast.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think you can read last line with just a method.

```
Do While fso.AtEndOfStream <> True
    fso.SkipLine
Loop

lines = fso.Line-1
```

something like this would not be faster?

Comment: That's still reading through every line one at a time, as opposed to [opening the entire file at once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50798424/8112776).