# Find number of rows in an already filtered Column A in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have got an Excel spreadsheet. This spreadsheet has just one tab in it. The Tab name is dynamic in nature and changes every week also the number of rows.

I have column A filtered already with a VBA macro. A1 has the header.
Now, I wanna find how many rows are there in this already filtered column A.
I am looking for any VBA function.
I have tried using Subtotal function.

```
=Subtotal(103,A2:A1345)
```

But I don't know the end range. As of now the end range is **A1345**. It will change every time in future if the new rows are added.

I tried multiple things but those did not work. I am quite new to VBA.

Comment: It is often helpful to post what you have tried, even if it doesn't work. That said, I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/excel-vba-better-way-to-find-last-row#38882823) is what you're looking for

Comment: If A1 will never be blank, you could use `=Subtotal(103,A:A)-1`.  Or, if there will be data below your table not to be counted, then format your table as a `Table` and use the structured reference:  `=SUBTOTAL(103,Table1[column_header])`

Comment: A1 has the header. Actual data is from A2. I have just now added that in the edits. When I do `=Subtotal(103,A:A)-1` excel gives me a circular reference error

Comment: Well, you can't have the formula in column A

Comment: Then you are putting the formula into column A. Use `=Subtotal(103, A2:A<row above the formula>)`

Comment: Thank you Ron - I applied that formula in a different column and it worked!!! . All this time I was pulling my hair that why am I getting Circular reference error each time. But now when I applied it in another column it worked!!! wow lovely :-) How do I mark this question as solved now?

Comment: @alisa I'll post my suggestion as an answer, and you can then mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If A1 will never be blank, you could use (in a column other than `A`)

```
=Subtotal(103,A:A)-1.
```

Or, if there will be data below your table not to be counted, then format your table as a Table and use structured references (and this formula could go into column A)

```
=SUBTOTAL(103,Table1[column_header])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the formula in column A if you use another column's last populated cell as the demarcation point.

If column B contains numbers then,

```
=subtotal(103, a2:index(a:a, match(1e99, b:b)))
```

If column B contains text then,

```
=subtotal(103, a2:index(a:a, match("zzz", b:b)))
```