# Retain color from different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have 20+ sheets with the same structure and I am trying to make a summarization on the first sheet. The issue I am facing is that I am a complete rookie when it comes to how to use vba.

The code below is what I thought was the first step, all the cells from `A2:A31` in blad5 should retain the background color into blad1 `E2:E31`, if I change the color in blad5 it would show take color on blad1 (All the cells in Blad5 `A2:A31` have a green background color)

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 Worksheets(Blad2).Range("A2:A31").Interior.Color = Worksheets(Blad1).Range("E2:E31").Interior.Color
 End Sub
```

My intention is to utilize a do loop over all the sheets (blad2-blad27) to blad1 which is my summarization sheet.

Would be grateful for a nudge in the right direction on how to do a function en do loop for the sheets (minus blad1 / sheet1) and how to properly write the `interior.color` macro.

With kind regards,
Fredrik

Comment: Do *all* the cells in `Worksheets(Blad1).Range("E2:E31")` have the *same* `Interior .Color`?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad the interior.color for blad1 E2:E31 are all white i.e no fill

Answer (score 0):

For the loop over the sheets you can use following:

```
For i = 2 To 27

Worksheets("Blad" & i).Range("A2:A31").Interior.Color=Worksheets(Blad1).Range("E2:E31").Interior.Color

Next i
```

Comment: Hi, I am gettting a error 13 when trying to compile the macro.

Comment: How did you dim your variables?

Comment: I haven't, I am just using the default dims from the sheets. The thing I explained which was pretty lackluster is the my summarziation sheet (blad1) has columns which correspond to blad2-blad27. So the second part Interior.Color=Worksheets(Blad1).Range("E2:E31") has to reflect this aswell.
One question, if I rename the sheets will excel vba still understand blad1 aso?

Comment: If you want to be renaming the sheets it is better than to use the VBA aliases in codes (it is the part that is shown in the VBA project window before the sheet name in the brackets. If you want to have all used cells colored on the sheet you can use ActiveRange property like here before you use the colors: 
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Select. If you want to clor just part that changes you can  try to find last row and column like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/excel-vba-better-way-to-find-last-row

Comment: And for the variables, set variables as a certain type at the beginning of the code like: Dim i As Integer. Error 13 type mismatch is a sign that the excel expects different datatype than the variable is used for.