# Update an array of filtered values VBA Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I want to filter a column of a table that has a list of IDs. 
The table updates automatically from a different Excel sheet.

If I use the Macro to filter the values, the values imported from the external reference are not filtered.

This is the code used for autofilter:

```
Sheets("Test").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$110").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "17547", "18521", "18694", "19212", "19815", "19857"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: You probably need to adjust the range where you filter on `$A$1:$E$110`. See [here how to find the last used row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38882823).

Comment: I'm sure that the range it's correct, cause the updated values from the external sheet are in the range, but before the updating, values are valorized in the table  like "N/D"