# Finding the value containing in the last non empty cell even if there is blank cell in the middle in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a macro in VBA that will find the last non empty cell in a column but there can be empty cells present in between. I want my program to search further if there is any non empty cell present in a column after it finds a blank cell. Then I want to store the value in some variable a.

The code that I used is `a = Range("B1").End(xlDown).value`, but this stops when it finds an empty cell. Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better way to find last used row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/better-way-to-find-last-used-row)

Comment: Thanks. This code gives the cell that is non empty. That means if in a coulmn the 5th cell from the above is non empty the code gives 5. But I want the value that the cell contains. I tried with `Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).value.Row` but it didn't work. Can you please tell me the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to have it this way?

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As String
a = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B1000000").End(xlUp).Row
b = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & a).Value
```

that way it'll look for the first used row from B 1.000.000 going up. 
a will be the number of the last used row.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But it does exactly the same as `Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`. That means it gives the index of the cell but not the value that it contains. I want to know the value.

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can use the row number to get the value out of it.

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked. Also `a = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B1000000").End(xlUp).value` works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you need if for the future:

`Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` will return the row number of the last non empty cell in column B.

`Range("B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value` will return the value of the last non empty cell in column B. So will do `Cells(Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row,2).Value`

Comment: Very correct! also note, that in this case `a = [INDEX(B:B,MAX((B:B<>"")*(ROW(B:B))))]` will work :)

Comment: Just a quick question. Does it work with cells as well? Instead of writing range can I write the code using cells? Something like `cells(5, 2 & cells.count).End(xlUp).Value`.

Comment: @zih `Cells` first number is row number, and second one is column number, so if you use `cells(5, 2 & cells.count)` it would throw an error. You can use it as `Cells(Rows.count,5).End(xlUp).Value` to get the value of last non empty cell in column 5 (that means column E)

Comment: @BigBen Yep. I don't know why in 2019 I posted it like that but you are right indeed.