# Transpose columns to rows from 1 sheet to another sheet with VBA with ongoing columns

Tags: excel, vba, transpose

I have a constantly-updating spreadsheet I use to track projects, but I want to create a summary view for internal stakeholders. I'm looking to transpose my columns to rows from a sheet named "Tasks" to the sheet named "Assessment Changes".

I tried to record a macro and this is what I recorded:

```
Sub TransposeColToRow()
    ' TransposeColToRow Macro
    Range("B3:B14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B20").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

The error message says: Run-time error '1004': This selection isn't valid. make sure the copy and paste areas don't overlap unless they are the same size and shape.

What I have currently (new projects get added to as a new column, so a new project would then go into Column I):

[image]

What I want is rows 2-10 being transposed to the "Assessment Changes" sheet like this, so the new columns get transposed to new rows:

[image]

So in my example above, when I add a new project in my "Tasks" sheet, the project gets added to Column I. But when I run the macro I had recorded, the error message pops up and doesn't copy any new columns to rows.

.

I was thinking of adding a button and assigning a VBA to it so that every time you click it, it will update with the new columns and transpose again. But I don't know how to do that. I'm fairly new to VBA so your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to S.O.. What have you tried so far and where is the problem, exactly? Seeing the code you currently have will make it a lot easier to help you

Comment: FYI, it's usually better to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58565667/edit) instead of adding information in comments.

Comment: In your question you state: "...the transpose stops at the last column I had set it to..." what does that mean, exactly? Where did you set it? etc... [this may help you clarify your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks, @cybernetic.nomad. I've updated the question and hopefully, that's clearer. Sorry, it's my first time posting a question, so I apologize if it's not completely clear.

Comment: So, in general, it's a good idea to [avoid using select in your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) (I know, the recorder did it, not you, but it causes a lot of beginner to think you _have_ to select). Once you know how to manipulate ranges without selecting, you can [get the last row & column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/better-way-to-find-last-used-row) or the [UsedRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.UsedRange) and from there, copy and the paste.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to locate the last column to copy:

```
Dim lastCol As Long

With Sheets("Tasks")
    'find the last used column on row 3
    lastCol = .Cells(.Columns.Count, 3).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Range(.Range("B3"), .Cells(14, lastCol)).Copy
End With

'paste and translose
Sheets("Assessment Changes").Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, _
              Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

as per your screenshots, you could try this:

```
With Sheets("Tasks").UsedRange
    .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 2).Offset(1, 2).Copy
End With

Sheets("Assessment Changes").Range("A6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this based on the above feedback and some googling help and it worked well:

```
Sub Transpose_columns_to_rows()
  Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, lr As Long, j As Long
  Set sh1 = Sheets("Tasks")  'origin
  Set sh2 = Sheets("Assessment Changes")  'destiny
  sh2.Range("A6", sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count)).ClearContents
  lr = 6
  For j = 3 To sh1.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    sh2.Range("A" & lr).Resize(1, 10).Value = Application.Transpose(sh1.Cells(2, j).Resize(10).Value)
    lr = lr + 1
  Next
End Sub
```

Thanks so much for all your help!