# 2 Problems with a VBA Macro and Date Formating

Tags: excel, vba

I have looked at other posts but cannot find anything that is similar enough to my problems. Any help will be appreciated. 
I have a set of dates that come in everyday; the dates come in the following format: DD.MM.YYYY (I live in a country that has the day first).  I need the data to change into DD/MM/YYYY. I then use these dates in a Vlookup as part of the data set that holds the information I wish to retrieve. 
I need help with the following problems:
Problem # 1

When I use the macro and switch the "." with the "/", days 1 to 12 have been switched to the following format DD/MM/YYYY. However, the actual month and day have switched. Currently working in April so 01.04.2020 has been switched to 04/01/2020 (Reading as January fourth); 04/02/2020 (February second and so on....). How can I prevent this from happening so that everything stays in place and just the "." and the "/" change.
Problem #2 
From day 13 and onwards the format looks right “13/04/2020”, however when I use it in the Vlookup, the formula will not bring any results back. In order for the Vlookup to work, I have to go to the cell that I just changed and press delete in front of the first digit, even though there is no space there; in order for the Vlookup to work.

Why does that happen? What can I do it so it work right after replacing the “.” and the “/”

Below is my code

```
Sub Dates()

Range(Range("G12"), Range("G12").End(xlDown)).Select


Selection.NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyy"

Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:="/", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyy" 

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do your 'dates' in the `dd.mm.yyyy` format come from?

Comment: From an excel file that is downloaded from SAP

Comment: If your regional settings use the date format dd.mm.yyyy you shouldn't need to change it to dd/mm/yyyy in Excel at all. If your data is dates, why do you first format it with a dot, then replace the dot? Why not format the dates with a / in the first step?

Comment: If SAP provides the Excel file, are the dates real dates or are they text that look like dates?? Can you format the dates in the grid with the ribbon? Does the format change? Then these are real dates and all you need to do is format them in VBA, not replacing of characters required.

Comment: Ok. I'm in Australia and based on my reigonal settings, the `dd.mm.yyyy` format isn't recognised as a date - to clarify, `01/04/2020` changed to the `Number` format stays the same whereas `01/04/2020` formatted as `Number` returns 43922

Comment: There are heaps of examples on the internet on how to solve this. Use Text to Columns and set the DMY or MDY in step 3. Or use Power Query and set the locale of the source data.

Comment: @SamuelEverson but you don't know what BetteJoan's regional settings are and if their dates are dates or not.

Comment: @teylyn perhaps I should have explicitly stated to check it.

Comment: @teylyn SAP downloads like that, we need it to be DD/MM/YYY for the report to work.  Can you provide me with at least one link please.

Comment: @SamuelEverson `dd.mm.yyyy ` is not recognized here either. Its just how SAP donwloads it. It is formatted as  `General `

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, rngDB As Range
    Dim s As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set rngDB = Range("G12", Range("G12").End(xlDown))
    vDB = rngDB
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        s = Split(vDB(i, 1), ".")
        vDB(i, 1) = DateSerial(s(2), s(1), s(0))
    Next i
    rngDB = vDB
    rngDB.NumberFormatLocal = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End Sub
```

### Error Image

[image]

### Correct Image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your code *as is*.

I strongly recommend reading and further understanding [How to avoid Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) to improve your code and reduce risk of runtime errors.

If you add this code to the bottom of your existing procedure (as it is shown in your question) it will loop through each cell and re-format it to the correct date value.

```
Dim myCell As Variant
Dim myRange As Range

Set myRange = Selection

For Each myCell In myRange
    myCell.Value = Format(CDate(myCell), "DD/MM/YYYY")
Next
```

You might find this link helpful also:

[Better way to find last used row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/better-way-to-find-last-used-row)

If you refine your code taking into account the information in both links, you will end up avoiding `.Select` and `Selection.` entirely, and your target range/cell will be less ambiguous.

---

I'd reformat it as follows:

**Note:** *I have written this on `Sheet1` of a new workbook, you would need to change the `Sheets("...")` reference to match your sheet name.*

```
Sub dates()

Dim myRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim myCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
        Set myRange = Range("G12:G" & LastRow)

        For Each myCell In myRange
            myCell.Value = Replace(myCell, ".", "/")
            myCell.Value = Format(CDate(myCell), "DD/MM/YYYY")
        Next myCell
    End With
End Sub
```

Now it's a lot clearer where on our workbook we are making changes which helps improve readability for yourself and others (such as other users on SO) along with reduces ambiguity and risk of `RunTime` errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the text to column advise this is what I did for it to work:

```
Sub Dates ()


Dim rg As Range

Set rg = Range("G12").CurrentRegion

    rg.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("H2"), ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, DataType:=xlDelimited, Other:=True, OtherChar:="."

    lr = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    Range("K2").Formula = "=DATE(J2,I2,H2)"

    Range("K2").AutoFill Range("K2:K" & lr)
```