# Run time error 1004 the sort reference is not valid?

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net, sorting

[image]I am running an Excel Macro from vb.net for sorting range of data and I receive this error as in the attached image

[image]

My Code is

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Set ws = Worksheets("Result_T10")
lastRow = Worksheets("Result_T10").Range("C2" & Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
with ws
ws.Range("C2" & lastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("C2" & lastRow), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With
```

So What is wrong in the code?

Thanks, Regards

Moheb Labib

Comment: Don't forget the `:` when doing a string mention to a range. Ranges are like `C2:C10`, `A1:A20` and so on. Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/38882823/9199828

Comment: Do you really mean `vb.net`? Looks like VBA to me

Comment: @ FunThomas, it is VBA but running it from VB.Net Interface

Answer (score 1):

You are treating the last row as an entire range and adding to the range.  You need to isolate the last row as a row number then create the range.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Set ws = Worksheets("Result_T10")
lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
with ws
ws.Range("C2:C" & lastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("C2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong in this line

```
lastRow = Worksheets("Result_T10").Range("C2" & Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
```

As `lastRow` is `Long` data type it can store number value only. Your current line returning a range not row. So add `.row` at the end of line like below.

```
lastRow = Worksheets("Result_T10").Range("C2" & Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Row
```

You can simplify this line with

```
lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: @ Harun24HR, I adjusted the lastRow as wrote but I still have the same error

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of your data in sheet?