# VBA code fails as soon as XML document is loaded

Tags: excel, xml, vba, load

I have the below code which takes an XML file from a shared location and loads it into Excel. As soon as the file is opened, i get a "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error" message.

```
Sub Load_XML()

Dim xml_file_path As String
Dim file_date As String

Worksheets("Start").Activate
file_date = Range("B1").Value

xml_file_path = "Y:\mydrive\" & file_date & "-000000_RREP1002.XML"

Workbooks.OpenXML Filename:= _
        xml_file_path _
        , LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList

Dim lstrow as Integer
Dim r as Range

lstrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count 

Set r = Range("A2:AF & lstrow")
```

The code errors before the last line is executed, i.e. as soon as the OpenXML is done.

Any ideas please what could be causing this issue?

thanks!

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: hi, sorry for being thick, but i am not sure how i can avoid the Select function here as I need to select a range of data which I dont know how many rows it is (it changes day on day) so the way i do it is selecting the top row and then using XlDown command. If i declare a range as a variable, would i not have to then somehow determine how many rows are in the dataset?

Comment: For that have a look here: [Better way to find last used row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38882823)

Comment: thanks, i have updated my code to amend the last line to the following, but i still get the same error:     lstrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count                                   Set r = Range("A2:AF & lstrow")

Comment: What format is the filename `YYYY-MM-DD_000000_RREP1002.XML` ?

Comment: The code is still the same in the question. Can you please [edit] and update the question with the new information you got?

Comment: yep, without the hyphens, so todays file is 20210623_000000_RREP1002.XML

Comment: @Pᴇʜ that's done, thanks.

Comment: Have you checked tha value of `Range("B1").Value`? Probably you need to format it correctly if it as a numeric date and not a text (looking like a date). Try `file_date = Format$(Range("B1").Value, "YYYYMMDD")`. Also check one time you have a hypen one time an underscore.

Comment: Also note that Excel has more rows than `Integer` can take. So you need to declare row counting variables as `Long` like: `Dim lstrow As Long`. Finally `Range("A2:AF & lstrow")` needs to be `Range("A2:AF" & lstrow)` the variable needs to be outside the string.

Comment: that part of the code works fine though as it can locate the file and open it. It is only after opening the file that my code errors out?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thank you very much! that last part has fixed it! Apologies for my basic questions.

Comment: @st87_top I added it as an anwser with some improvements, so you can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor the code like below.

```
Public Sub Load_XML()
    Dim wsStart As Worksheet
    Set wsStart = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Start")
 
    Dim file_date As String
    file_date = wsStart.Range("B1").Value  ' make sure all ranges have a worksheet specified!
    
    Dim xml_file_path As String
    xml_file_path = "Y:\mydrive\" & file_date & "-000000_RREP1002.XML"
    
    Workbooks.OpenXML Filename:=xml_file_path, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList
    
    Dim lstRow As Long
    
    
    lstRow = wsStart.UsedRange.Rows.Count 
    ' I recommend a more reliable method to find the 
    
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = wsStart.Range("A2:AF" & lstRow)
```

I recommend a more reliable method to find the last usted row than using

```
lstRow = wsStart.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

It is better you use

```
lstRow = wsStart.Cells(wsStart.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

This will find the last used row in column `A`. Adjust the column to one that has always data and no blanks.