# Loop through date range with a monthly step

Tags: vba, date, for-loop

I have an issue with VBA, I am trying to loop into a date range with a monthly step but i'm struggling at the "monthly step" part.

Actually i am able to get this output:

```
13/08/2021 
14/08/2021 
15/08/2021 
16/08/2021 
17/08/2021 
18/08/2021
```

And  what I am trying to get is more like:

```
08/2021 
09/2021 
10/2021 
11/2021 
12/2021 
01/2022
```

Here is my code:

```
aIndex = 1
    For Each Cell In Range("F2", Range("F2").End(xlDown))
            aIndex = aIndex + 1
            For J = Range("D" & aIndex) To Cell
                Debug.Print J
            Next J

    Next Cell
```

The "F" and "D" column simply contains dates with format "DD/MM/YYYY" and I'm looping between "D" and "F" date.

Thanks in advance,

Nicolas.

Comment: `Debug.Print Format$(J, "mm/yyyy")`

Comment: Thanks braX but i want only 1 output of "08/2021" not one for every days.
Here is the actual output:
```
07/2021
07/2021
08/2021
08/2021
08/2021
08/2021
08/2021
```

Comment: Do a for next loop from the month and year of the min date to the month and year of the max date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of way to do it, but trying to keep it similar to what you have, removing things that are not needed, and using a Dictionary instead:

```
Sub test()
  Dim sDate As String
  Dim dict As Object
  Dim Cell As Range

  Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  For Each Cell In Range("F2", Range("F2").End(xlDown))
     sDate = Format$(Range("D" & Cell.Row), "mm/yyyy")
     If Not dict.Exists(sDate) Then
       dict.Add sDate, 1
       Debug.Print sDate
     End If
  Next

  Debug.Print "Total: " & dict.Count

End Sub
```

There are things you can do with the Dictionary afterwards if your `Debug.Print` is not exactly what you needed.

Comment: Also, you may want to read about [Better way to find last used row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/better-way-to-find-last-used-row)