# Want to paste the data in next row each time i run this macro

Tags: excel, vba

I need that when i run this code every time data should be pasted to next row.  Salary sheet is raw data file , and final slaary is final sheet where data is to be copied.
Please help

```
Sub TestThat()

'Declare the variables
Dim DataSh As Worksheet
Dim finalSh As Worksheet
Dim monthsRange As Range
Dim rCell As Range
Dim i As Long

'Set the variables
Set DataSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Salary Sheet")
Set finalSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Final Salary")

Set monthsRange = DataSh.Range(DataSh.Cells(3, 1), DataSh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    'I went from the cell row3/column1 (or a3) and go down until the last non empty cell

    i = 2

    For Each rCell In monthsRange 'loop through each cell in the range

        If rCell = Sheets("Menu").Range("E6").Value Then 'check if the cell is equal to "range e6"

            i = i + 1                                'Row number (+1 everytime I found another "range e6")
            finalSh.Cells(i, 1) = rCell.Offset(0, 0) 'month
            finalSh.Cells(i, 2) = rCell.Offset(0, 1) 'emp id
            finalSh.Cells(i, 3) = rCell.Offset(0, 2) 'emp name
            finalSh.Cells(i, 4) = rCell.Offset(0, 3) 'designation
            finalSh.Cells(i, 5) = rCell.Offset(0, 22) 'gross salary

        End If

    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `i =2`, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/better-way-to-find-last-used-row) and incorporate to `i`.

Comment: What is your issue with this code ?

Comment: each time i run this code, data paste gets overlapped., instead of getting paste in next blank row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Criteria Rows

- A quick fix would probably be, instead of `i = 2`, to use:

  ```
  i = finalSh.Cells(finalSh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  ```
- Here's a more flexible way to do it.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyCriteriaRows()

    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Salary Sheet"
    Dim sCols As Variant: sCols = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "W") ' read
    Const slrCol As String = "A" ' Source Last Row Column
    Const sCol As String = "A" ' Source (Criteria) Column
    Const sfRow As String = 3
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Final Salary"
    Dim dCols As Variant: dCols = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E") ' write
    Const dlrCol As String = "A"
    ' Criteria
    Const cName As String = "Menu"
    Const cCellAddress As String = "E6"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, slrCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If slRow < sfRow Then Exit Sub ' no data in column range
    Dim slrg As Range ' Source Last Row Column Range
    Set slrg = sws.Range(sws.Cells(sfRow, slrCol), sws.Cells(slRow, slrCol))
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = slrg.EntireRow.Columns(sCol)
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dlrCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Cells(dlRow + 1, dlrCol)
    
    ' Criteria
    Dim cws As Worksheet: Set cws = wb.Worksheets(cName)
    Dim cCell As Range: Set cCell = cws.Range(cCellAddress)
    Dim Criteria As String: Criteria = CStr(cCell.Value)
    
    ' Other
    Dim nLower As Long: nLower = LBound(sCols)
    Dim nUpper As Long: nUpper = UBound(sCols)
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim n As Long

    ' Read/Write.
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        If StrComp(CStr(sCell.Value), Criteria, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            For n = nLower To nUpper
                dCell.EntireRow.Columns(dCols(n)).Value _
                    = sCell.EntireRow.Columns(sCols(n)).Value
            Next n
            Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1)
        End If
    Next sCell

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Month '" & Criteria & "' processed.", vbInformation

End Sub
```