# How can I use COUNTIFs or VBA to look through 3 columns and count the values in a row?

Tags: excel, vba, match, vlookup, countif

The data set that I have has multiple instances of names and employee numbers. I am looking to find the instance where the employee's id number, name and category line-up then count the values in the row.

for example.

```
                     1/01  1/02   1/03   01/04   01/05
12345 Daniel Start      7      2      1       7      3
12345 Daniel Break      30     1      1       1      30
12345 Daniel End        12     8      7       12     10
12345 Daniel Over 4     0      1      1       0      1
12345 Daniel Total Hr's 4.30   5      5       4.30   6  


**If I want to find how many times Daniel worked over 4 hours ( 12345 Daniel Over 4 ) how can I use Excel to count the number of 1's in the row where Daniel is over 4?**



Extra Notes: I'm open to trying VBA or formula's...I'm stumped.
```

Comment: The labels are standard? This means after the employee name there's always "Start" "Break" "End" "Over" and these exist in the dataset. I assume that "Total Hr's" is the one that you wish to calculate, am I correct?

Comment: Yes after each employee they're labeled that way. I'm most interested in counting up the values in the " Over 4" row.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VBA, you don't need to restrict yourself to `CountIfs` limited abilities, you can loop through every row and count up the values with your own custom script. Get the last row of the sheet with [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/better-way-to-find-last-used-row) and then you can loop through the sheet like:

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim SearchValue1 As String, SearchValue2 As String, SearchValue3 As String
    SearchValue1 = "12345"
    SearchValue2 = "Daniel"
    SearchValue3 = "End"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Long, SearchCount As Long
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If ws.Cells(i, 1) = SearchValue1 _
            And ws.Cells(i, 2) = SearchValue2 _
            And ws.Cells(i, 3) = SearchValue3 _
        Then
            SearchCount = SearchCount + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Rows(i), "<>") - 3
        End If
    Next

    Debug.Print SearchCount
End Sub
```

This could also be turned into a [User Defined Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-custom-functions-in-excel-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f) that accepts the SearchValues and the search range as arguments, and then returns the `SearchCount`.

Move the code into a code module, and modify it like so:

```vb
Function CustomCount( _
                     SearchRange As Range, _
                     SearchValue1 As String, _
                     SearchValue2 As String, _
                     SearchValue3 As String _
                    )
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = SearchRange.Parent
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Long, SearchCount As Long
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If SearchRange.Cells(i, 1) = SearchValue1 _
            And SearchRange.Cells(i, 2) = SearchValue2 _
            And SearchRange.Cells(i, 3) = SearchValue3 _
        Then
            SearchCount = SearchCount + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Rows(i), "<>") - 3
        End If
    Next

    CustomCount = SearchCount
End Function
```

As a UDF you can use it inside your Excel formulas like `=CustomCount(A:C,"12345","Daniel","End")`

This UDF could be further improved by adjusting the code to allow a variable number of SearchValues. You could make some optional, or you could make them into a [ParamArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/paramarray). But I will not put that in this answer and leave that for you to explore if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a VBA approach, I would tweak Toddleson answer, but according to your comments, it may not be necessary and only an index/match will be able to satisfy the scenario stated:

[image]

The formula would be

```
=NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH("*"&B10&" Over*",B2:B5,0)),B10&" Over",""))
```

Comment: Yes this helps! But the name and the other labels are separated from each other into two columns  like:                                                                                                                        
    Daniel                       Start                      7

Comment: @YANEALLARIAM It is even easier that way, take a look into [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/index-and-match-with-multiple-criteria)

Answer (score 0):

If you dispose of the newer dynamic array features of *Excel 2021+/MS Excel 365*, you might procede as follows using a tabular formula input:

- [`Filter()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) the numeric data columns (e.g. `D:H`),
- connect all three filter conditions (*id* in column `A:A`, *name* in col `B:B`, *type* in col `C:C`) as logical ***And*** by multiplying `(A:A=12345)*(B:B="Daniel")*(C:C="Over 4")` to get one boolean result and
- execute a simple `Sum()` upon the filtered row(s):

```
    =SUM(FILTER(D:H,(A:A=12345)*(B:B="Daniel")*(C:C="Over 4")))
```

**Note:** Of course you can replace any explicit search value also by sheet references getting sheet inputs of the search criteria.

***Example:*** assuming an *id* input e.g. in cell `B2` of Sheet1:   `=SUM(FILTER(D:H, (A:A=Sheet1!B2)* ... ))`.

---

*In case you dispose of the [`Let()` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) allowing to organize inputs systematically, you might also enter the following formula:*

```
    =LET(data,D:H,id,12345,name,"Daniel",type,"Over 4",SUM(FILTER(data,(A:A=id)*(B:B=name)*(C:C=type))))
```

**Further hint:** You might want to have a look at the advanced `Lambda()` function, too which by now is only available to members of the *Insiders  Beta program* - see [Lambda - the ultimate excel worksheet function](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/blog/lambda-the-ultimatae-excel-worksheet-function/)