# How to know the last row with data, no matter if the row is hidden or not

Tags: excel, vba

until now, to know which is the last row with data I use this code:

```
Function GetPrimeraFilaLibre(paramNombreHoja As String, paramColumnaReferencia As String)
    GetPrimeraFilaLibre = Sheets(paramNombreHoja).Range(paramColumnaReferencia & "65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
End Function
```

This function take as parameter the sheet that I want to know the last row and as second parameter the column of reference that I will check if it has data or not.

The problem that this function doesn't work if there is hidden rows. I would like to know the last row with data, no matter if it is hidden or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba. If your data doesn't contain emtpy rows, using `CurrentRegion` might be the easiest solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38882823/9199828

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Range.Find` can be used to return the last row whether or not there are hidden rows.

```
Function GetPrimeraFilaLibre(paramNombreHoja As String, paramColumnaReferencia As String) As Long
    With Sheets(paramNombreHoja).Columns(paramColumnaReferencia)
        GetPrimeraFilaLibre = .Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
    End With
End Function

Function GetLastRow(SheetName As String, ColumnNameOrIndex As String) As Long
    With Sheets(SheetName).Columns(ColumnNameOrIndex)
        GetLastRow = .Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
    End With
End Function
```

### Addendum

As VBasic2008 pointed out, we would need to make an adjustment to handle `MergedCells`.

```
Function GetLastRow(SheetName As String, ColumnNameOrIndex As String) As Long
    Dim Target As Range
    With Sheets(SheetName).Columns(ColumnNameOrIndex)
        Set Target = .Find(What:="*", After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
    End With
    GetLastRow = Target.MergeArea.Rows.Count + Target.Row - 1
End Function
```

Comment: I mostly agree with this and most often use this way but there are some 'special' cases. You know how `SpecialCells` treats visible cells equally even if they are visible by `AutoFilter`. Unfortunately, the `Find` method distinguishes these two cases and fails to find hidden cells in a filtered range (worksheet). Also, it is unreliable with merged cells. Worth pointing out is that the `xlFormulas` parameter 'makes it see' the hidden cells. So one could conclude that there is no universal way to find the last row. Other notable methods are by using `End`, `CurrentRegion`, `UsedRange`, `CountA`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I prefer `Range.CurrentRegion` but it is hard to recommend t without knowing the exact use case.  It's a shame that we cannot have a `ListObject` variable without converting the range to a `ListObject`.   How nice would it be if `Range`  had an `AsListObject` method.  e.g. `Set Table = Range.CurrentRegion.AsListObject`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I adjusted for possible `MergedCells`.  Thanks!