# Range to Last Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to send emails of tables inside each sheet to recipients. I've got everything working except for making the range dynamic (to last cell).
I want to send data from cell `A1` to last cell in `Column G`. I'm not having any luck making it work. The part below is an excerpt of the code which contains the ill formed range. Any help is much appreciated.

```
Sub Email1()

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next


Set rng = Sheets("Rec1").Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
           vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38882823/9199828