# VBA: select all the cell from a specific one to the last with values

Tags: vba

My aim is to select with VBA for example all the cells from A1 to A10 (the last one with values).

Is the function AllValueDowns applicable? If so, how does it work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to find last used row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/better-way-to-find-last-used-row)

Comment: Could you share the code of the `AllValueDowns`  function? Basically, without it, you could do `Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Select` for the active sheet.

Comment: Wks_Sb.Range("A9", Range("A9").End(xlDown)).ClearContents
    Wks_So.Range("A9", Range("A9").End(xlDown)).ClearContents
    'Wks_So.Range("A9:A50").ClearContents                                                                                       



(The problem was that at the "wks_so" line, the code gave Error 1004)

Comment: `Wks_Sb.Range("A9", Wks_Sb.Range("A9").End(xlDown)).ClearContents`  All calls to Range/Cells should be qualified with a worksheet reference.