# How can I turn a Range ("A1:A11") into (A"1: until empty cell")

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have tried to just set the range to ("A:A") but that makes the table too large and my computer freezes up, I have also tried to input a line like `Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)` but that is not recognized by VBA.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/better-way-to-find-last-used-row `Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Select`

Comment: yeah, unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: @Excelnoob what exactly didn't work?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, new to the forum, I keep forgetting that a generic answer won't help solve a problem. Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Select did not work.

Comment: You need to follow the link attached to @braX 's comment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to find last used row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/better-way-to-find-last-used-row)

Comment: @Cameron Critchlow's code below worked like an absolute charm! Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first define your last row by referencing the last cell in the column then use `.End(xlUp).row` to find the last row number. You can then use that row number to build cell references, or even save the range as a range variable like I did:

```
Sub Last_Row_Example()
    
    Dim LastRow As Long   'Last Row as a long integer
    Dim RG As Range       'A range we can reference again and again very easily
                          'Consider renaming it to something more descriptive.
                          'for your particular situation
    
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' Here we store the "LastRow" Number
    Set RG = Range("A1:A" & LastRow) ' Here we build a range using the LastRow variable.
        
    RG.Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, RG, , xlYes).Name = _
            "Table3"
        Range("Table3[[#All],[Ticker Name]]").Select
        Selection.ConvertToLinkedDataType ServiceID:=268435456, LanguageCulture:= _
            "en-US"
        
End Sub
```