# How do I find the number of last row and paste right below it?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to paste data from one sheet to another but the last row of data varies everytime. The line I use to paste the data is "**Application.Goto ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("CICLICO").Cells(LastRow+1, 2)**"

If my LastRow is 10 I paste the data at the row 11, but it can be 9, 50, 89... I would like a code to find that last row and identify it as LastRow. Any ideas?

I  haven't tried anything because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: something with `.End(xlDown)`.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/better-way-to-find-last-used-row