# i want to copy a value in cell N2 to all other cells in the same column - I do not know where the end of the column as it dynamically changes

Tags: excel, vba

i can copy whole rows but finding it difficult to locate the end cell of the row N and then copy everything from N2 to last the row. The end of the row - N  ( cell) changes in length as the data imported changes

[image]

```
Sub Copy_To_Lastrow()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Lastrow As Long

    Sheets("Meeting1").Select
    Range("N2").Select

    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp) + 1
    Range("n2").Copy Cells(Lastrow, "AN")
    'Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'Range("n2").Copy Cells(Lastrow, "AE")
    'Lastrow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     Range(Lastrow).PasteSpecial.Values

     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One way, avoiding any copy/paste:

```vb
Sub Copy_To_Lastrow()
    Dim lr As Long
    With Worksheets("Meeting1")    '<<should specify a workbook here...
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("N2:N" & lr).Value = .Range("N2").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: this copies over the 1st row Cell N1 and leaves all the others except N2 blank. I was trying to copy everything in N2 cell.value to to the end of specified i.e. - last cell in column n

Comment: You used column AN to find the last-occupied row in your posted code:  `Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp)`  so I was assuming that was correct.  You could use any other fully-populated column instead.

Comment: ok. thanks. Yes my code was just not working and i was looking in the row whereas i should be looking in the column - cell.value. And i am not sure what the answer is right now.

Comment: If you just need to know the last occupied row on the sheet you can use something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/63521561/478884    If that's not the problem then I'm not sure what to suggest.

Comment: the challenge is that i need to copy the value in N2 to the last cell in the range which dynamically updates in size. So first i need to find the cell that is blank in Row N then copy the value from N2 into this value and then repeat this to the end of the range.

Comment: So "fill down N2 to the end of the column" but what exactly determines the "end" of the column ?   Would it be the same row as the last value in some other column?  If not that then what?

Comment: In the example sheet above the last row is the last row.

Comment: yes - very simple - amended as follows :With Sheets("Meeting1")
  .Range("N2").AutoFill .Range("N2:N" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).row)
End With