# Error 424 when trying to find last row in a table

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel on a Mac.

I am new to this and am following some YouTube videos - I am pretty sure I copied the code correctly, but I get 'error 424' on the `MFST_Lastrow = MFST.Range.Rows.Count` statement when I run it?

```
Sub UpdateMasterSupplier()

Dim MSFT As ListObject
Set MSFT = MasterSupplierFile.ListObjects("MSF_Table")
Dim MSFT_LastRow As Long


MFST_Lastrow = MFST.Range.Rows.Count

MsgBox (MFST_Lastrow)

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to find last used row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/better-way-to-find-last-used-row)

Comment: `MsgBox (MSFT_Lastrow)` should not have any parentheses btw.

Comment: You have a typo in your variable name: You write Dim M**SF**T As ListObject, but you are using M**FS**T  when you want to read the number of rows. Always use **Option Explicit** to avoid such errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're after?

```
Sub UpdateMasterSupplier()

    Dim rngMSFT As Range
    Set rngMSFT = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MSF_Table").Range
    
    Dim MSFT_LastRow As Long
    MFST_Lastrow = rngMSFT.Rows.Count
    
    MsgBox (MFST_Lastrow)

End Sub
```