# How to avoid looping through empty cells

Tags: excel, vba

I wanna compare 2 lists, lists have around a few thousands entries.

if I loop through using a for each loop like this :

```vb
For Each cell In Worksheets(sheetname).Range("H:H")
```

it loops through all the cells (which is much bigger)

The solution I found is to have an empty counter that will break out of the loop once it reaches 5 consecutives empty cells

```vb
Function some_func(sheetname As String)
    Dim blankCount As Long

    blankCount = 0
    For Each cell In Worksheets(sheetname).Range("H:H")
        If blanckount >= 5 Then
            Exit For
        End If
        If (IsEmpty(cell )) Then
            blankCount = blankCount + 1
            GoTo continue_
        End If
        blankCount = 0
        ' do something
continue_:
    Next cell 
End Function
```

I find this way to be ugly and was wondering if there was a more elegant approach?
Note: I am new to vba, i come from C langages

Comment: Use the specialcells feature.

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/better-way-to-find-last-used-row

Comment: If you will also show **what "compare" means**, you will maybe receive some more recommendations or a piece of code. I do not understand why you need to stop after 5 consecutive empty cells. Can you explain, at list, why that?

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/2292722) to a similar question.

Comment: Watch out for the typo on the 5th line - `blanckount` vs `blankcount`. Using `Option Explicit` would highlight these for you.

Answer (score 1):

The [UsedRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.usedrange) property could be used in this situation. It creates a rectangular Range of all used cells. You can further reduce it to a column with the [Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.columns) property with a parameter for the index of what column you need. The H column is the 8th column, but it might not be the 8th in your UsedRange if the A column is empty and so on.

```
For Each cell In Worksheets(sheetname).UsedRange.Columns(8).Cells
    ' do something
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UsedRange` to limit the range to just those cells that have been altered on the worksheet.

You can use `Intersect` to find a join of all cells in your 8th column that are also within the used range.

[image]

```
With Worksheets(sheetname)
    
    For Each cell In Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns(8)).Cells
      '.. do something with cell
    Next

End With
```