# Excel macro to find a cell string in a column and copy all data below it and paste into another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a scenario where i need to copy all data in a columnA below a specific cell which has certain set string value. I tried below code but the data below the string in columnA is not getting copied and not pasting to another sheet. Any help wis appreciated.

```
Sub Macro11()
 Dim strSearch As String
 Dim fVal As Range
 Dim lastrow As Long
 Dim wk As Workbook

'Set the value you want to search
strSearch = "*Question*"

Set wk = ThisWorkbook

With wk.Worksheets("Sheet1")
         'Find string on column A
    Set fVal = .Columns("A:A").Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
    If fVal Is Nothing Then
        'Not found
        MsgBox "Not Found"
    Else
    'Found
        MsgBox "Found at: " & fVal.Address
       .Range("A:A" & (fVal.Row)).Copy
        Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
 End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Assign values is more efficient than `Copy/PasteSpecial`
- The syntax of `.Range("A:A" & (fVal.Row))` is incorrect; it should be something like `.Range("A10:A25")`.
- If you don't need to copy cell `fVal`, chang to `.Range(fVal.Offset(1), .Cells(lastrow, "A"))`

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range(object)?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm143072)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144187)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Sub Macro11()
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim fVal As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim wk As Workbook
    'Set the value you want to search
    strSearch = "*Question*"
    Set wk = ThisWorkbook
    With wk.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Find string on column A
        Set fVal = .Columns("A:A").Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If fVal Is Nothing Then
            'Not found
            MsgBox "Not Found"
        Else
            MsgBox "Found at: " & fVal.Address
            lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlup).row
            With .Range(fVal, .Cells(lastrow, "A"))
                wk.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Resize(.Cells.Count).Value = .Value
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent. This script works seamlessly. Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 1):

Try this .
instead of

```
Else
'Found
    MsgBox "Found at: " & fVal.Address
   .Range("A:A" & (fVal.Row)).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
```

use this lines

```
Else
'Found
    MsgBox "Found at: " & fVal.Address
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row ).Value = fVal.Value
End If
```

Comment: It says Runtime error 1004. It is only copying and pasting the fVal cell value. It does not copy all data below the fVal cell value. Therro line is   
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: Dose fVal return more then one result ?  try debug print fVal.value  to check what is the returned value. in case the return result is  more then One cell you will need different approach.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code. This is one to consider:

```
.Range("A:A" & (fVal.Row)).Copy
```

If fVal.Row is row 27 ... this makes A:A27. That's not what you want.

I think you want:

```
.Range("A" & (fVal.Row) & ":A" & (someVariableForEndOfRange)).Copy
```

If you don't want to explicitly include the row of the flag/found text, add one to fVal.Row before your string concatenation. You need to explicitly identify the end of the range - VBA doesn't seem to like it if you end the range object with only the column.

After that, your code will still throw some scoping errors - the With statement did not quite work as you intended.

I changed the message box calls so you can bug check the range you're moving.

I also ran your code through this formatter - it has been mentioned elsewhere on stack overflow: https://www.automateexcel.com/vba-code-indenter/

```
Sub Macro11()

    Dim strSearch   As String
    Dim fVal        As Range
    Dim lLastRow    As Long
    Dim strSel      As String
    
    'Set the value you want to search
    strSearch = "*Question*"
    
    'Find string on column A
    Set fVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:A").Find(strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
    If fVal Is Nothing Then
        'Not Found - end
        MsgBox "Search returned no matches."
        GoTo LastLine
    End If
    
    'Find last used row
    lLastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    strSel = fVal.Address & ":$A$" & lLastRow
    MsgBox "Copying Range: " & strSel
    
    'Do the copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(strSel).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
LastLine:
End Sub
```

Comment: See here for discussion about finding the last used row. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/better-way-to-find-last-used-row

Comment: Updated to find & utilise last row in column search.

Comment: Wonderful. This script too works seamlessly. Great Work. Thanks