# Dynamically Select data in a table to copy into a new workbook using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a macro that will copy the data being generated via a query and pasting it into a new sheet. The end goal of the macro is that when the data is pasted into the sheet that it is just the values, not in a table, and not updatable with data refreshes. I want the link broken. The issue that I am running into is that the data sizing might change. This macro needs to work if there are 3 rows or 30 rows.

```
Sub Macro2()
   Range("Observation_Report").Select
   Range("E30").Activate
   Selection.Copy
   Sheets("Issues").Select
   Range("J27").Select
   Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

My problem is specifically with the `Range("E30").Activate`. There is no guarantee that there will be data at row 30 and if that is the case, nothing is copied and inserted because nothing was selected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Better way to find last used row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882321/better-way-to-find-last-used-row)

Comment: Why do you activate cell E30?

Comment: I recorded this macro as a base for what I want to build. That is how excel does the actions

Comment: You're not utilizing the full potential of the macro recorder. Select `A1` on each sheet. Then select sheet `Issues` and only then start recording. Then paste the new code into your question and we'll see what can be done.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `End(xlUp).Row` to locate the last non-blank cell on Col J
- Assign values to the destination cells without table formatting

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144187)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Macro2()
    Dim tabRng As Range, lastRow As Long
    With Sheets("Issues")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
        Set tabRng = .Range("Observation_Report")
        .Range("J" & lastRow + 1).Resize(tabRng.Rows.Count, tabRng.Columns.Count).Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```